# Некорректно работает выделение ссылок

Tags: дефект, ссылки

По-разному показываются ссылки в предпросмотре и после отправки сообщения:

```
https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/api/pascalprecht.translate.$translateSanitization
```

https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/api/pascalprecht.translate.$translateSanitization

До отправки выглядит так:

[image: скриншот предпросмотра]

А после - так:

[image: скриншот вопроса]

Разница в `.$translateSanitization` - оно входит в ссылку в предпросмотре, но не входит в итоговую. Версия из превью правильнее.

## Some links are parsed incorrectly

```
https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/api/pascalprecht.translate.$translateSanitization
```

Fragment `.$translateSanitization` is included into the link in preview (first screenshot), but is outside of the link in final version when the question/answer is poted. Preview version is correct.